# ImportError: No module named 'code.helper'

Tags: python

This is probably a question that has been asked multiple times, but I couldn't find a post with the answer I am looking for.

This is my structure:

```
/myproject
 --/code
   --/__init__.py
   --/helper.py
 --/tests
   --/test_helper.py
 --/docs
```

#### code/helper.py

```
def testFunction(x)
    return x + 1
```

#### test/test_helper.py

```
import unittest
from code.helper import testFunction

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(testFunction(3), 4)
```

Whenever I run 'python3 -m unittest test_helper.py' from ~/home/user/Projects/myproject/tests - I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'code.helper'; 'code' is not a package
```

I am not receiving any syntax errors.

Comment: do your folders have `__init__.py` files

Comment: this is literally the structure I have now, my tests-folder doesn't contain an init.py, my code folder does. It's an empty one

Comment: `myproject` isn't on your Python path. It works when the working directory is `myproject`, since the current directory is always on your path, but you are in `tests`.

Comment: add an empty `__init__.py`  file under tests too and see if that resolves. And i think you should be running the unitest from `myproject`

Comment: @HamzaHaider this will not solve the problem. Cf chepner's comment for the real issue here.

Comment: an empty init to /tests/ doesn't resolve the issue. So if myproject isn't on my path, how do I fix this

Comment: Issue resolved. I understand the error. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `myproject`  in your Python path. It works when the current directory is `myproject`, because the current directory is always on the Python path. When you change to `tests`, though, Python no longer knows where to find `code`.

```
192% pwd
/Users/chepner/myproject
192% python3 -m unittest tests/test_helper.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
192% cd tests
192% pwd
/Users/chepner/myproject/tests
192% python3 -m unittest test_helper.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_helper (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_helper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/chepner/myproject/tests/test_helper.py", line 2, in <module>
    from code.helper import testFunction
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.helper'; 'code' is not a package


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

The simple fix is, don't run the tests from the `tests` directory! Another solution, though, is to add `myproject` to the path before running the tests:

```
% PYTHONPATH=.. python3 -m unittest test_helper.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

You can add anything to `PYTHONPATH` that will correctly resolve to `myproject`; I just used the trivial relative path `..` here, but an absolute path like `PYTHONPATH=/Users/chepner/myproject` would work, too.